# Private and final methods

Tags: java, visibility

I am trying to get a better understanding of private and public methods. I am trying to make a private method called `GRID_SIZE` and let that equal the length(m) of my grid, however, I am getting a message saying that it cannot be resolved into a variable. My understanding is that if a method is private only the class can access it and if a method is public any class can enter. So I am confused as to why I can't take a variable from the public method to a private method.

```
public class trial1 {
    

    private static final int GRID_SIZE = m; 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            int m = 8; 
            char[][] grid = new char[m][m];
            
            for (int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j<grid[i].length; j++) {
                    grid[i][j] = '*';
                    StdOut.print(grid[i][j]);
                }
                
            StdOut.println();
                
            }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to write `private static final int GRID_SIZE = 8` instead and then use `GRID_SIZE` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a static **field**, not a method. The visibility is not relevant to the question.

Static (class) variables simply cannot be set before the class is initialized; there is no `m` until the `main` method is executed (after the class is instantiated by the JVM). Plus, you've made the field `final`, so it cannot be modified within the main method, anyway.

Perhaps you want this?

```
public class Trial1 {

    private static final int GRID_SIZE = 8; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] grid = new char[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is around **scope**.

Variables defined within a method are only visible within that method. So in your code the variable `m` is only accessible by code inside the `main` class.

`GRID_SIZE` is a private static field (not a method) and that means it is accessible by all code within the class.

If you want `GRID_SIZE` to be assigned a value defined in method scope (e.g. `m`) then you need to remove the final from `GRID_SIZE` and set it from within the `main` method.

Something like:

```
public class Trial1 {

private static int GRID_SIZE ; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int m = 8; 
        GRID_SIZE = m;
        char[][] grid = new char[m][m];
        
        for (int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<grid[i].length; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = '*';
                StdOut.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            
            StdOut.println();
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Please note this is just an example of how to change `GRID_SIZE`. If you just want `GRID_SIZE` to always be a particular value then as the previous answer states you could just set it directly to 8.